# How to hide the code statements in R markdown?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

When knitting the R markdown code I am also getting the code statements in the output document.How do I hide the code statements in R markdown?

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the code output using echo=FALSE in the R markdown code.

```
{r, echo=FALSE}
```